# Python: Why does a timer function need be be called via a lambda function?

Tags: python, timer, lambda

I had an error before. ("NoneType object is not callable")
And i found a solution to my problem by instead of calling the "update" function directly to call it via a lambda function.

The code prints the start time every second for 10 seconds, and then updates the time it prints once.

(This is a proof of concept code for a bigger project of mine. I use this construct to create a new timestamp upon which a log file is opened. to instead of opening the old log file the next day, creating and using a new one every day at 00:00:00)

```
now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
delta_t_seconds = 10

def update():
    global now
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print "Time updated"
    return

t = timer(delta_t_seconds, lambda: update())
t.start()

while (True):
    print("Time is:" + now)
    time.sleep(1)
```

My question is:
Why do i have to call it via a lambda function?:

```
t = timer(delta_t_seconds, lambda: update())
```

instead of directly:

```
t = timer(delta_t_seconds, update())
```

It just seems silly to call function2 of which the sole purpose is to call function1. Compared to calling function1 directly.

Comment: I guess it should not be called in place when the timer is defined but when it fires. You did not give the code that defines or imports `timer` so it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a lambda, you can pass the function directly:

```
t = timer(delta_t_seconds, update)
```

By doing `timer(delta_t_seconds, update())` (note the extra parentheses), you call `update` once, which returns `None`. `timer` then tries to call `None`, which is impossible (`None` is not callable), giving you the error you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't**.

`update()` isn't a function, it's a call to a function. Thus it performs the update at the moment it is called. You need to pass in a function, which would be `t = timer(delta_t_seconds, update)`. Note the missing brackets after `update`.

Answer (score 1):

With `t = timer(delta_t_seconds, update())`, you are passing the return value(call the function first to get it) not the function itself to `timer`.

If you want to pass `update` to `timer`, just use `t = timer(delta_t_seconds, update)`, you don't need to use `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `timer` expects the second argument to be a callable (fx a function) while your function `update` does not return a callable (in fact it returns nothing at all - that is `None`). A lambda is ONE way to create a callable from an expression (the expression is evaluated when the lambda is called). Note that the lambda `lambda: update()` is equivalent of `update` (that is a function object).